# Adding days to multiple records in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to insert some data from one table to another but I need to increase the date based on record before inserting the data into the second table. My SQL statment looks like this:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO WPReadinessMasterTbl SELECT WPReadinessEntriesTbl.RequiredDate FROM WPReadinessEntriesTbl WHERE ProjectType= " & ProjectType

db.Execute (sql)
```

I need to add WPReadinessEntriesTbl.RequiredPrepDays to WPReadinessEntriesTbl.RequiredDate before the record goes in. How can i do this easily?

Answer (score 0):

You can use *DateAdd*:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO WPReadinessMasterTbl " & _
"(YourFieldname) " & _
"SELECT DateAdd('d', WPReadinessEntriesTbl.RequiredPrepDays, WPReadinessEntriesTbl.RequiredDate) " & _
"FROM WPReadinessEntriesTbl " & _
"WHERE ProjectType = " & ProjectType & ""
```

Comment: This is still giving me the error "No destination field name in INSERT INTO statement..." How can i fix this?

Comment: I think I only need something like `sql = "UPDATE WPReadinessEntriesTbl SET RequiredDate = DateAdd('d', RequiredPrepDays, RequiredDate)"` but this does not work.